# How do I submit a form with no form ID and no submit ID, but known hidden value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

the situation I'm struggling with is that there are more forms on the page that looks like this (the hiddenId is different in each form):

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value="111222">
<input type="submit" value="Proceed">
</form>

<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value="111333">
<input type="submit" value="Proceed">
</form>
```

How do I submit with javascript (I don't mind using jQuery) a specific form that includes hiddenId of a wished value? Thank you for your help!

Comment: why can't you give the forms a class or id?

Comment: name is deprecated, you should use id.  never use the same id for more than one element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something along these lines should get you started:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type === "hidden" && inputs[i].value === "111333") {
        inputs[i].form.submit();
    } 
}
```

If you can use jQuery:

```
$("input[type='hidden'][value='something']").closest("form").submit();
```

Comment: @Neil - Yeah, that might be a bit better :) Edited.

Comment: Thank you very much, both solutions work perfectly! *Note for dummies like me: the code must be at the end of the page.*

Comment: @SiddSidd - The code doesn't have to be at the end of the page, it just has to run when the DOM is fully loaded (otherwise there will be `input` elements to loop over). Putting the code at the end of the page means the code runs once everything else has (including your `input` elements).

Answer (score 6):

document.forms is an array. `document.forms[0]` is the first one.

Elements work the same way:

`document.forms[0].elements[0].value` etc.

You can loop through until you have the value then submit the current form:

```
document.forms[x].submit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Access all of the forms using `var allForms = document.forms;`

loop through them as needed to access inputs

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) or one of the various JavaScript libraries that emulate it on older browsers to find the hidden input element, then use its `form` property to access the form and invoke the `submit` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to the form and submit button:

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value="111222">
<input type="submit" value="Proceed" id="submit1">
</form>

<form method="post" id="form2">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value="111333">
<input type="submit" value="Proceed" id="submit2">
</form>
```

Then use jQuery to submit the form:

```
$("#submit1").click(function() {
    form1.submit();
}
$("#submit2").click(function() {
    form2.submit();
}
```

Comment: *IF* the original poster was using (or wanted to use) jQuery, yes.

Comment: The original poster stated "How do I submit with javascript" that is why i took this approach.

Comment: This doesn't help me as I can't change the html; I'm writing an extension for Google Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, i was not aware of this. I will post an alternate solution.

Comment: Why would you bind a click handler to submit it when clicking the submit button already does that :\